# SEO - Redirect domain root to different url for landing page

Tags: seo, redirects, 302-redirect, landing-page

I plan to to put my web app to say `http://example.com` but for now i have only landing page with signup form. I thought about putting LP to `http://example.com/welcome` and I feel that this should be `302` redirect from domain root since it is in nature temporary measure. Is that correct? What seo implications will this have?

Would it be better to have my landing page on `/` and change content when my app is ready?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both them are good. But it is better to go with your second option.

Edit : After launch your website fully, your aim is to get more traffic to example.com. isn't it? So start to optimize it now. At least you can set title and meta description as your future goal. Then add sign up page to it. When you launch the site you need to have change the content only.